# discord.py RuntimeWarning: coroutine was never awaited

Tags: discord.py

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="**hi**", color=discord.Color.green())
        embed.add_field(name="", value=f"(**hello**)", inline=False)
        Origin_embed  = await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=False)
```

```
async def perform_toss_check_pay(name, amount, interaction: discord.Interaction, random_name, Origin_embed):
    res = toss.check(name.strip(), amount)
    print(res)
    if res.get('result') == True:
        MSG = res.get('msg')
        embed = discord.Embed(title="**``✅`` ┃ checked**", color=discord.Color.green())
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=False)
        Interaction.delete_original_response(Origin_embed)
    if res.get('msg') == '입금 미확인':
        Interaction.delete_original_response(Origin_embed)
```

it said RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Interaction.delete_original_response' was never awaited
Interaction.delete_original_response(Origin_embed)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback. help me

`i tried await Interaction.delete_original_response(Origin_embed) Interaction.delete_original_response(await Origin_embed) Interaction.delete_original_response.Origin_embed`

Comment: Use interaction without a capital I and await it.

Comment: it said TypeError: Interaction.delete_original_response() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Please fix your formatting. Also, there are some either typos or errors in your code. For example, the variable `Interaction` (the I is capitalized) versus `interaction` (in the parameters, uncapitalized.)

Answer (score 0):

The TypeError is because you are trying to pass in an argument to the function, but it takes in the only argument it needs.

```
@bot.tree.command(name="asd")
async def asd(interaction:discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Message")
    await interaction.delete_original_response()
```

The `interaction.delete_original_response()` will always delete the first response to the interaction. You cannot pass in any arguments.